# Selinux Denies Starting Service on Android 8

Tags: android, c++, selinux, ril

Recently I am working on Android 8 and blocked with selinux issue…

I create a “ppp” service in init.rc to start pppd as below:

```
service ppp /system/bin/pppd call gprs
user root
group system radio
disabled
oneshot
```

But it failed when starting this service with command “setprop ctl.start ppp”.

The selinux is already set to permissive mode but still shows as follows, and service is not started:

> console:/ # [  430.567622] init: Could not ctl.start for service ppp: File /system/bin/pppd(labeled "u:object_r:ppp_exec:s0") has incorrect label or no domain transition from u:r:init:s0 to another SELinux domain defined. Have you configured your service correctly? https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials

The ppp.te and file_contexts is not changed:

ppp.te:

```
typeattribute ppp coredomain;

domain_auto_trans(mtp, ppp_exec, ppp)
```

file_contexts:

```
/system/bin/pppd    u:object_r:ppp_exec:s0
```

Any information to solve this problem is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use  “setprop ctl.start ppp”, the service is started from init.

Try with this policy:

```
domain_auto_trans(init, ppp_exec, ppp)
```